# In Drupal 7, I've created a subtheme, how do I assign that theme to a particular page?_

Tags: drupal, themes, drupal-7

So I have my parent theme and my subtheme both enabled in Drupal 7.

I've specified in the .info of the subtheme that the base theme is the parent theme.

Once I create a page, how do I tell that page to inherit my subtheme?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**:
So what I want to do is create several new pages (about 20) that are going to follow the same template file as the rest of my Drupal site. However, they are all going to have different background images, link colors, and heading styles. I figured the Drupal subthemes would let me create a page that inherits the main stylesheet, but lets me modify it as needed for the new pages. Sounds like that's not what subthemes are for.

*Thanks to Matt V:*
Subthemes allow you to use an existing theme as the starting point for creating your own custom theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong but if you want to implement different themes on different pages, it sounds like what your looking for is "hook_custom_theme", it's pretty straight forward, basically you just add:

```
function mymodule_custom_theme(){
  //Some custom logic here
  $node=node_load(arg(1));
  if($node && $node->type=="my_custom_type"){
    return 'my_custom_theme';
  }
}
```

your return value must be a string that equals the machine readable name of the theme you're switching to...

re-reading your post, you may want to look into the template_preprocess_html and template_preprocess_page functions. Inside of these functions you can set and alter your template variables, i.e.

```
$vars['styles']=drupal_get_css();
```

once you've done that you could easily swap out css tags with a little bit of logic, this method would allow you to only use one theme with multiple css files....

Answer (score 2):

to activate a subtheme, you need to enable it and set it as default.

The subtheme (or any theme for that matter) is for the site as a whole.  To theme an individual page you could create a template for that specific page, or use the Panels module - there are many ways to skin a cat in drupal.....

here is some more info [Drupal 7 theme system changes](http://pingv.com/blog/a-peek-at-drupal-7-theme-system-changes)

Comment: Hmm, okay thanks.  I guess I don't get the purpose of subthemes then.  Why would you create a subtheme that is going to get inherited by the site as a whole? 

http://drupal.org/node/225125

Comment: Subthemes allow you to use an existing theme as the starting point for creating your own custom theme.

Comment: they also allow the base theme to be upgraded without losing all your custom templates and css etc.

Answer (score 2):

By using **themekey** module you can achieve this

Refer http://drupal.org/project/themekey

Answer (score 1):

To have your theme activated site-wide and used as default for ALL pages,  you need to go in admin/appearance and activate your theme, and then click on the link beside the theme "Define as default".

To have your theme used on one specific page, that would be a bit trickier to do, just clarify if that is what you really wanted.

Comment: * Sub-theming allows you to re-use parent theme's styling, allowing you to override or add css markup to the subtheme.  I sometimes do this to avoid hacking parent theme, allowing for easy theme upgrades with modifications all safely tucked away  in a subtheme.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  So what I want to do is create several new pages (about 20) that are going to follow the same template file as the rest of my Drupal site.  However, they are all going to have different background images, link colors, and heading styles. 

I figured the Drupal subthemes would let me create a page that inherits the main stylesheet, but lets me modify it as needed for the new pages. It sounds like that's not what they are for...

Comment: You would need to look into template overides for that, there are many ways to do this in Drupal, here is a [video tutorial](http://lin-clark.com/blog/intro-drupal-7-theming-fields-and-nodes-templates) that touches on the subject.